# Making .env file and modifty codes on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, dotenv

Anybody help me on creating .env file and modify the codes!
this is discord.js v12
i cant modify the .env codes on this codes!
but it didnot working
pls help me in this system! and it is yarn installed method!

js file => RushGamerzClient.js

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class RushGamerzClient extends Client {

    constructor(options = {}) {
        super({
            disableMentions: 'everyone'
        });
        this.validate(options);

        this.once('ready', () => {
            console.log(`Logged in as ${this.user.username}!`);
        });

        this.on('message', async (message) => {
            const mentionRegex = RegExp(`^<@!${this.user.id}>$`);
            const mentionRegexPrefix = RegExp(`^<@!${this.user.id}> `);

            if (!message.guild || message.author.bot) return;

            if (message.content.match(mentionRegex)) message.channel.send(`My prefix for ${message.guild.name} is \`${this.prefix}\`.`);

            const prefix = message.content.match(mentionRegexPrefix) ?
                message.content.match(mentionRegexPrefix)[0] : this.prefix;

            if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

            // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            const [cmd, ...args] = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

            if (cmd.toLowerCase() === 'hello') {
                message.channel.send('Hello!');
            }
        });
    }

    validate(options) {
        if (typeof options !== 'object') throw new TypeError('Options should be a type of Object.');

        if (!options.token) throw new Error('You must pass the token for the client.');
        this.token = options.token;

        if (!options.prefix) throw new Error('You must pass a prefix for the client.');
        if (typeof options.prefix !== 'string') throw new TypeError('Prefix should be a type of String.');
        this.prefix = options.prefix;
    }

    async login(token = this.token) {
        super.login(token);
    }

};
```

js file => index.js codes on here

```
const RushGamerzClient = require('./Structures/RushGamerzClient');
const config = require('../config.json');


const client = new RushGamerzClient(config);
client.login();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options to fix the problem:

Use .env file that has
`DISCORD_TOKEN="<your-token>"`
then use `dotenv` (install using `npm i -G dotenv`) on the top of your file, and login with environment variable

```
require('dotenv').config();

...

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: it will be shows You must pass the token for the client